# Sitecore 8: Getting application error when removing broken links

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I try to remove broken links on my master database using the tool provided by the following url.
http://mysite/sitecore/admin/RemoveBrokenLinks.aspx

After some time the process being interrupted and I got the following error on Sitecore log.

```
6220 10:56:26 INFO  Removing broken link- Database: master, Item: /sitecore/content/Home/blog/2012/January/13/totaljobs-group-benefit-from-expert-sitecore-consultancy-delivered-by-codehouse, Field: __Renderings, Target item database: master, Target item path: /sitecore/content/global/Codehouse Widgets/Mini Form Widgets/newsletter-subscription
6220 10:56:26 INFO  Done
6220 10:56:26 INFO  Removing broken link- Database: master, Item: /sitecore/content/Home/blog/2012/January/13/totaljobs-group-benefit-from-expert-sitecore-consultancy-delivered-by-codehouse, Field: __Renderings, Target item database: master, Target item path: /sitecore/content/global/Codehouse Widgets/Mini Form Widgets/sitecore-demo-text-only
6220 10:56:26 INFO  Done
6220 10:56:26 ERROR Error looking up template field. Field id: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. Template id: {0437FEE2-44C9-46A6-ABE9-28858D9FEE8C}
Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Null ID is not allowed.
Parameter name: fieldID.
Actual value was {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.TemplateSection.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.GetField(ID fieldID)

6220 10:56:26 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Null ID is not allowed.
Parameter name: fieldID.
Actual value was {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.TemplateSection.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.DoGetField(ID fieldID, String fieldName, Stack`1 stack)
   at Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetTemplateField()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.FieldTypeManager.GetField(Field field, String runtimeValue)
   at Sitecore.sitecore.admin.RemoveBrokenLinks.FixBrokenLinksInDatabase(Database database, Boolean serializeItem)
   at Sitecore.sitecore.admin.RemoveBrokenLinks.FixBrokenLinksOnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you made a cleanup database before doing RemoveBrokenLinks? 
  Tu clean up database go to ->Control Panel->Database->Clean up Database
 I guess you have some orphaned items (items without templates) 
 When you are doing a Cleanup Database next tasks are executed:

1. Removes items that have parents, but the parents are not in the item
    tree.
2. Removes invalid language data.
3. Removes fields for non existing items.
4. Removes orphaned items.
5. Removes unused blob records.
6. Removes fields from orphaned items removed in step 4.
7. Rebuilds the Descendants table (which stores parent/child relationships).
8. Clears all caches.

Comment: I tried this. I Cleaned the database and rebuild the link databases. But still I'm getting the above error. Is there any way to manually delete these links ?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite odd that it didn't resolve the issue by using **Clean up Database** or by **Rebuilding the link database**.

Few questions:

1. During the clean up and rebuilding process, did you find any
   relevant entry related to the issue in your Sitecore log? If yes, could you please paste it here, as well.
2. Reading the stack traces you provided, it looks like that there is/are orphaned template(s) and that's the reason why it throws an `Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Could you please repeat the same rebuild and clean up process, and let us know the result of the 2nd run?

Alternatively, if you find repeating the process a very time consuming and performance heavy then you might want to consider creating a **LinkDatabaseRefreshTool.aspx** file, put it inside the \Website\admin folder with the following code as your processor:

```
foreach (var specificItem in itemList)
{
    specificItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
    Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.UpdateReferences(specificItem);
    specificItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Create an asp:Textbox and a submit button that invokes this method OnClick. Open the tool by accessing the `http:\\YOUR_WEBSITE\admin\LinkDatabaseRefreshTool.aspx`

I experienced the same issue before, and I just rebuild it again and that resolved the issue. Maybe just the same solution on your end, still worth a try.